# How to show recently used apps in the home lens in dash search instead of installed applications?

Tags: 15.04, unity-dash, lenses

As I rarely use Libre Office Calc but use the calculator all the time, I would like to see calculator show up first when I start typing `calc` only.

This is the default behavior in the applications lens which gives priority to recently used applications. However, this behavior is lost in the home lens. Is there a way to fix this?